# How do you configure CAS for database and Duo MFA?

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, apereo, duosecurity

So I've built a CAS war file (version 6.6.10) and it launches fine in Apache Tomcat (see attached screenshot) but I've been unable to get it to work with the Oracle database authentication and Duo MFA that I require. I've tried putting the settings into both the cas.properties file and the application.properites files then building the war again but nothing seems to work. I'm not sure what I'm failing to configure to get this to work so any help would be greatly appreciated.[image]

I've tried putting the settings into both the cas.properties file and the application.properites files then building a fresh CAS war file.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. Upon reading documentation it's said to enable MFA using global providers like
cas.authn.mfa.triggers.global.global-provider-id=mfa-radius (in my case).

Please try this once and check if that's working or not.

Comment: Thank you for the response, where does that setting need to be put along with the other variables like Duo and JDBC settings?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the property in your cas.properties file or application.properties..wherever u r accessing the properties

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).